# Error installing Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm installing pandas in windows 8. I have installed vc for python. And I type the command easy_install pandas but I get the error shown in the image [image] [image] [image]. Please help.(I have also tried pip but it doesn't work either.)

Comment: As a note for the future. It's typically bad practice to post screenshots of error codes just like it's bad practice to post screenshots of code. Much better to copy and paste the error, that way in the future people with the same error code can search it and find a thread such as this.

Comment: I would suggest looking for binary installers, or using a third party distributor like  `anaconda`. Python libraries with extension modules are a pain on windows.

Comment: @cel: ok i've installed anaconda now what should i type on cmd to install pandas

Comment: in general the command is `conda install pandas`, but it should be already pre-installed for you.

Comment: yes its already there! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download the adequate binary of Pandas here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas and feed it to easy_install e.g. `easy_install C:\Users\toto\pandas-0.15.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`

Comment: You're welcome, you may consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: I actually used anaconda. Thanks a lot for helping!